# $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ where $I=\langle 1+x^2 \rangle$ let $y$ be the coset of $x$ in $R$ then

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ where $I=\langle 1+x^2 \rangle$  let $y$ be the coset of $x$ in $R$ then

1. $y^2+1$ is irreducible over $R$
2. $y^2-y+1$ is irreducible over $R$
3. $y^2+y+1$ is irreducible over $R$
4. $y^3+y^2+y+1$ is irreducible over $R$

I have not understood the problem at all, could any one help me to understand the probelm and then how to solve it?

Comment: I suspect that something is wrong. You declared $y$ to be an element of $R$. It seems to me that $R$ is <insert the name of a fitting structure>, and thus it has no irreducible elements.

Comment: Algebraically closed field? (It isn't one)

Comment: Just a field :-)

Comment: Jyrki's on the money, unless the question's trying to check your understanding of things. We have that $\,R\cong\Bbb C\;$ , so all the questions seem to be either wrong, or pretty trivial...and it never matter whether algebraically closed or not: it is a field!

Comment: I guess Miosaki's confusion comes from the the difference between a polynomial over a ring, and an element of a ring being irreducible. The question asks for the latter when it looks like it is the former.

Comment: Also it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ not to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: True: I missed that $\,\Bbb Q\,$ there and just saw the $\,R\,$ and mistook it by the reals. It doesn't really matter, it still is a field.

Comment: I want to delet this question as I am not sure the question was rightly asked in the question paper from which I have written

Answer (score 1):

$1+x^2$ has no root in $\mathbb Q.$ So $1+x^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q\implies R$ is a field.

Consequently $R$ has no non zero non unit element. So all of the above four options are false.